# Wordpress how to use session ? I want to use Shopping Cart

Tags: php, session, wordpress

I want to develop online order & shopping cart. My solution is use Session to save user's carts. But Wordpress not provide Session. Have any solution to develop that function?

Comment: What do you mean WordPress doesn't "provide Session"? WordPress is PHP. You have everything available to you that PHP normally provides.

Comment: How to use Session in Wordpress ?

Comment: The same way you would use it in plain PHP...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WordPress doesn't use sessions so you can either start one yourself, or consider creating a database table for storing shopping cart contents and instead use the database.

If you want to start a session, your plugin should call [`add_action`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_action) using `init` as the hook and in your function call, use the code:

```
if ( session_id() == '' || (function_exists('session_status') && PHP_SESSION_NONE == session_status()) ) {
    // no session has been started yet
    session_start();
}
```

That code will start a session early on in the WordPress request cycle so you can then use it in your plugin to store shopping cart data in the session.

Comment: I'm sorry for duplicate comment, but: If you must use native sessions for some reason (there are other ways https://pressjitsu.com/blog/wordpress-sessions-performance/ ) you should consider closing the session right after you're done with it - http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-write-close.php